# Need Open As Administrator In Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, administrator

I'm unable to get `Open as Administrator` option In Nautils menu, I tried to follow many Tutorials from different sites, but none of them are working.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin -y && nautilus -q`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu Tweak-> Admins -> Scripts, move Browse as root script to enable scripts.

run this command:

```
nautilus -q
```

And run nautilus, right-click **on a file**, you can see in "Scripts" sub-menu "Browse as root".But, i think there is a bug in script, because if you right-click on empty area in folder, "Browse as root" can't show the folder you want.So you must right-click on a file in the folder. No problem for me, i use this script.

Comment: Which Script Sorry???

I`ant Have Any Scripts  Can You Provide The Scripts??

Comment: "Browse as root" script. İf you install Ubuntu Tweak, you can see this script in Ubuntu Tweak-> Admins-> Scripts.

This script provides you browsing as root on Nautilus and openning files as root.

Comment: How To Open File As Root ??????

Comment: You can open files as root when you are browsing as root and also you can do it directly with right click.Run following commands in terminal.
in order to get root privileges:
`sudo su`
then

`gedit .gnome2/nautilus-scripts/Open\ as\ root`
Now a gedit windows must have opened.Copy and paste the following code:

`for uri in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS; do

gksudo "gnome-open $uri" &

done`

Ctrl+S to save file and back to the terminal and type:
`sudo chmod +x .gnome2/nautilus-scripts/Open\ as\ root`

Now you can see Open as root option where Scripts sub-menu in nautilus right-click menu.

Comment: Resource: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-open-files-as-root-via-a-right-click/

Answer (score 1):

there isnt in linux "Open as Administrator" . you can open a software as root but you need

terminal`sudo program` you need write or program will want password.

Comment: Actually there is, see `sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin -y && nautilus -q`